# Using defaultHandleClick of react-chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-chartjs-2

So I'm using react-chartjs-2 in my Functional Component. I'm using a Line chart

`return <Line height='600px' options={options} data={data} />`

And I want to do some custom to the defaultLegendClickHandler and I'm doing it like this:

```
import { defaults } from 'react-chartjs-2';

const defaultLegendFunction = defaults.global.legend.onClick;

const options = {
      legend: {
         display: true,
         onClick: function(event, legendItem) {
            defaultLegendFunction(event, legendItem);
            //My custom Function
         }
      },
   };
```

Then I got the error

```
caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'chart')
```

Which is because the 'this' is undefined in the default function of defaults react-chartjs-2 since every Chart Component is written in Class Component

```
core_defaults._set('global', {
    legend: {
        onClick: function(e, legendItem) {
            var index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
            var ci = this.chart; //'this' here is undefined
            var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(index);

            // more default code from react-chartjs ...
```

How can I pass 'this' into this default function? Or is there any solution that I can add my custom function to that legendHandleClick without override the default function?